# After creating android studio library I cannot add many comman dependencies

Tags: java, android, gradle, build

I am trying to create a java library. I got that far. Then I want to import packages from the the Android studio sdk. 
Then I go to file project structure and try to add a dependency to my library. I add `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1` to my dependencies because this is what my other android studio apps did to import most of the sdk packages I think. Then I build it and get this error :

```
Error:(4, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1
```

Install Repository and sync project
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog

I dont understand why I can add `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'` to my main android project but not to a library file.

The sdk is properly set up with my android studio. 
I don't understand. Thanks guys.

Comment: could you show the gradle file please?

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the dependecies in the file build.gradle ?

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    ...
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    /*testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'*/
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```